# form sent before the file was selected

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a standart form in HTML with inputs fields, and the last input is type="file". As there is no css way to design this input I make this input invisible by making it height and width = 0. And put "on top" of this invisible input, button that I design as I wanted. The button working as suppose to be, but in the end when I fill up all the form and push this button to select file, it open me a window to select the file, and simulteniosly sent the form. So in result it sent the form without file.So as I understand it some how acting as sumbition input.

So how to fix this problem - that button just select the file without sending form? For sending form I have input type=submit

So the part of html form:

```
<input type="file" name="file_up" id="upload_hidden" accept="image/*,image/jpeg" onchange="document.getElementById('upload_visible').value=this.value">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('upload_hidden').click();" id="upload_visible">+</button>
<input  type="submit" name="registr" value="Ready" size=15 id="reg_cmpl" />
```

Comment: You can use `label` to customise css of `input type=file`. I find that better approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `type` of a `<button>` is `submit`.

If you don't want to submit the form when you click it, don't use a submit button in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

`<button>` is `type="submit"`

explicitly set it to `type="button"` instead

```
<input type="file" name="file_up" id="upload_hidden" accept="image/*,image/jpeg" onchange="document.getElementById('upload_visible').value=this.value">
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('upload_hidden').click();" id="upload_visible">+</button>
<input  type="submit" name="registr" value="Ready" size=15 id="reg_cmpl" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the button type and try again like following :-

```
<input type="file" name="file_up" id="upload_hidden" accept="image/*,image/jpeg" onchange="document.getElementById('upload_visible').value=this.value">
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('upload_hidden').click();" id="upload_visible">+</button>

<input  type="submit" name="registr" value="Ready" size=15 id="reg_cmpl" />
```

It may help you.